# oracle call procedure in a cursor loop

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT AUDITORID 
        FROM SOL.GROUPS WHERE STATUS = 1;
```

I need for each AUDITORID that returns the statemnet to call the procedure `INSERT_LD_PER_AUDITOR (VAUDITORID)`

how to do that?

Comment: @Pirate nothing make some inserts

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS411

Comment: Do you mind sharing what `insert_ld_per_auditor` does?  I suspect you would be much better off changing the procedure to execute on a whole data set at once instead of individual "auditors". That way, you can avoid cursors all together, which would be much better.

Answer (score 4):

If you're sure you want loop you can use:

```
begin
  for x in (SELECT AUDITORID FROM SOL.GROUPS WHERE STATUS = 1) loop
      INSERT_LD_PER_AUDITOR(x.AUDITORID);
  end loop;
end;
```

but as sstan wrote it is probably better to refactor procedure to process all data.

Answer (score 0):

You cant call procedure via SQL statement 
And you have at least 2 ways how to resolve it.
1) Create pl_sql function and set call procedure into function

```
create or replace function F_INSERT_LD_PER_AUDITOR (VAUDITORID NUMBER) 
   return NUMBER
is 
begin 
  NSERT_LD_PER_AUDITOR (VAUDITORID);
  return 0;
end;
/
```

and call it function

```
SELECT F_INSERT_LD_PER_AUDITOR(AUDITORID)
    FROM SOL.GROUPS WHERE STATUS = 1;
```

2) wirte pl/sql and use LOOP as in previous comment